# android horizontal vertical scroll layout with center

Tags: android, xml, centering, horizontalscrollview

I need create something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKsOm.png) in xml, but it is not possible to center inner object in scrollView with child horizontalScrollView.

here is code example:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/matrix_table"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

                <!-- auto generated rows -->

            </TableLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</ScrollView>
```

and here is [unexpected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jM23x.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a child view to `fill_parent` doesn't work very well in ScrollViews. Instead, you should set the child view dimensions to `wrap_content` and use `layout_gravity` :

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >
    ...

</HorizontalScrollView>
```